# xlst value-of not appearing

Tags: xml, xslt

I have in a xslt file

```
 <xsl:for-each select="content/task/*">
      <xsl:if test="name()='header'">
           <img src="sectionheadarrow.png"></img><span><xsl:attribute name="class">contentsectionheader</xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of select="header"/></span>
      </xsl:if>
 </xsl:for-each>
```

The image appears but the value of the header node does not.

If I loop over content/task then the header value will appear but once I add the * I do not get the header value.

Anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the **xsl:for-each** loop, you are already positioned on the **header** element. Your **xsl:value-of** expression will be relative to that, so is looking for a child element called **header** under the current **header** element.

To fix it, just replace this line...

```
 <xsl:value-of select="header"/>
```

With this

```
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
```

Comment: Thanks. Awesome. I was looking for other ways of getting that like @value but that did not popup.